# Pandas: produce a multiple bar plot based on conditional over column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a DataFrame

```
gender  A  B
M       a  1
M       b  3
F       a  0
F       b  4
...
```

I'd like to produce a multiple bar plot where of B on y axis and A on x axis where the bars are separate per gender, that is, bars for gender M are next to those for gender F.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='A', columns='gender', values='B').plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Would you also happen to know if there's a way to select the colours of the two 'gender' sets of bars?

Comment: `.plot(kind='bar', colors=['red', 'blue'])`